# Mongo - Epoch Date comparison

Tags: mongodb, mule, mongodb-query, dataweave

I am stuck with Epoch date comparision in Mongo DB. Below is my scenario, could any one please help me out the provide some pointer?

### Scenario:-

1) Converting batchRunDate(1990-10-09T00:30:00Z) to epoch date(result is 655410600000).
2) I have one field in mongo db named lastModifiedDate which stores the field in string format (values is "/Date(1477560978000)/") Since this field is consumed AS-IS from source and passed AS-IS to the target, requirement is to keep the filed type as String.

Requirement - I want to fetch all the records from data base for which lastModifiedDate >=   batchRunDate.

ISSUE - When I am running  the query... 
{ "lastModifiedDate " : {$gte:"/Date(655410600000)/"}} it is not fetching the required records. It seems in MongoDB this comparison works entirely differently.

Can any one please let me know what what is the issue? and what is the correct way/query of comparing two epoch date?

Thanks in advance for your guidance!! :)

Comment: How did you store the date in mongo like what method did you use ?? Why is it prefixed with Date ???

Comment: it is strored in String format. Actually it is getting consumed in AS-IS way from source system. So, my code would simply generate query to compare this date.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but I dont think that is a date comparison and it will not work

Answer (score 1):

It is doing exactly what you are asking to do.

try  "less than".

```
{ "lastModifiedDate " : {$lte:"/Date(655410600000)/"}}
```

the value is for lastModifiedDate is less than 655410600000